# My company increased my notice period during my probation, I need some advice

Tags: contracts, notice-period

So during my probational period of 6 months my old boss left and I took up his position with no change to my side of the agreement, the director of the company approached me and said because they could not afford to lose me they wanted to increase my notice period to 2 months (I have been here 5 months at this point) I couldn't turn him down at the time because I felt if I did they would consider me a risk and not allow me to pass my probation period, however 3 months down the line I feel the company has taken advantage of my kind nature to the point where I can't even ask to be up to the same level of pay as people in my company who in the hierarchy are supposed to be under me, I like this company but I can't keep working for them, however I can't leave easily (without risk) as no company would wait 2 months for someone to leave before hiring them.

I felt under duress of losing my job when I signed the contract, and at this point I regret it every day...

Anyone have any advice to what I can do?

Comment: You may want to mention your location. A 2 month waiting period wouldn't be a major hurdle here, but here is certainly not where you are (as you couldn't have a 6 month probationary period here). And thus sorry, no advice from my side.

Comment: If you are in India this is trouble for you.  If you are in Canada or the US not so much.

Comment: @Myles Please stop spreading nonsense based on your half-baked information. There are no such issues here in India. 99.9% of employees in India don't have any issues with their notice period, the remaining 0.1% people face issues because they join dubious employers without verifying their background.

Comment: @MaskedMan - so how do you account for all the questions on relieving letters?  As far as I understood, you can't move job without one, so you are at the mercy of the employer's wishes notice wise (which I think is Myles's point)

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager It looks like you have some issue in reading my full comment, so let me help you a bit: *"the remaining 0.1% people face issues because they join dubious employers without verifying their background."* Do you know the size of the Indian workforce? If this relieving letter were such a huge problem, wouldn't you expect more than a few dozen questions on those? You guys are either falling to confirmation bias or deliberately avoiding rational thinking. Doesn't your "at will" employment in US *literally* mean you are at your employer's mercy? :P

Comment: @MaskedMan - I wouldn't know, I'm in Scotland and we're not an "at-will" country

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager I have myself changed jobs 4 times, and never faced any issue with relieving letters. I also know about 50 people in the IT industry who have never faced any issues with the relieving letter. Why? Because all these people join reputed companies which follow a well-defined process. Employees who face issues are those who either joined a company with suspicious credentials (and hence, no work ethics) or those who do not clear their dues (such as refusing to return company laptops and such). I don't feel any sympathy for such idiots. They ruin my country's reputation here.

Comment: @TheWanderingDevManager Okay, fair point, but his first comment specifically mentioned US and Canada, so I was also commenting in the same context.

Comment: @MaskedMan - but that's the thing.  OK you've worked for reasonable employers, but given the relieving letter requirement, if the employer decides he wants you to have a 6/12 month notice you have no way out.  Myles was comparing with North America where if the employer said that you could just say "no, bye" with little repercussions.   It affects an answer to the poster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23471/discussion-between-masked-man-and-the-wandering-dev-manager).

Comment: @MaskedMan I made my comment based on the fact that pressuring someone into taking a two month notice period while still under probation sounds like a dubious employment practice.  WanderingDev has my perspective right.  Almost no consequences in North America for failing to follow through with your notice period, potentially big headaches for the same behavior in India.

Comment: @Myles OK, then maybe my rantish comments were misdirected. I am seriously tired of people who keep saying that just because some 500-odd people faced an issue due to relieving letter, *an entire country* sucks, and even more so, of people claiming "superiority" because their country doesn't use relieving letters. Something is different from what you are used to doesn't mean it is bad. But I agree that wasn't *your* intention, sorry for that.

Answer (score 1):

You only have two choices, since you signed the revised agreement:

1) if you don't plan to leave any time soon, this may not be worth worrying about. Focus on your job.

2) Save up enough funds to live on while you do another job hunt (or make plans for temporary jobs to fill that gap) and give notice. You need the savings in case they decide to let you go before you've found another job.

I don't think there's anything else we can offer you.

Comment: Is the fear of losing my job if I didn't sign it not significant in any way?

Comment: I'm afraid not.

Comment: ... but you may need local legal advice to be sure.